# Two docker container (nginx and a web app) not working together (linux)

Tags: linux, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I built both containers using a Dockerfile (for each).  I have the NGINX container pointing (proxy_pass http://localhost:8080) to the port that the web app is exposed (via -p 8080:80).  I am able to get it to work when I just install NGINX in the linux machine, but when I use a dockerized NGINX, I just get the default NGINX index.html.  Do I have to build both containers using Docker-Compose.yml file (as oppose to Dockerfile) when I want the containers working together?  Sorry, if I didn't put any code, but at this point, I'm just wanting to know if I'm taking the correct approach (using Dockerfile or Docker-Compose).

Comment: The Nginx proxy needs access to the host (!) network for this to work. `--net=host`. Without it, `localhost` refers to the proxy (`localhost`) which likely has nothing on `:8080` and certainly not your web app.

Comment: Docker Compose (conventionally) solves this by putting containers onto a virtual network. The difference then would be that, rather than mapping everything onto host ports, each container (called a service) gets a unique name and a container called `proxy` could refer to a container called `web` on port `8080` as `http://web:8080`

Comment: @DazWilkin Thanks, it worked.  I still had to change some stuff in the configuration files because I had two "Server" sections with same server_name and the one that pointed to my web app was the one getting ignored.

Comment: I'll repost as the answer. SO should permit promoting comments to answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Nginx proxy needs access to the host (!) network for this to work, e.g.:

```sh
docker container run ... --net=host ... nginx
```

Without it, `localhost` refers to the proxy (localhost) which likely has nothing on `:8080` and certainly not your web app.

Alternatively, if the proxy's container (!), can resolve|access the host then processes in the container can refer to host-accessible ports using the host's DNS name or IP.

Docker Compose (conventionally) solves this by putting the containers onto a new virtual network. The difference then would be that, rather than mapping everything onto host ports, each container (called a service) gets a unique name and a container called `proxy` could refer to a container called `web` on port 8080 as `http://web:8080`.

You may achieve similar results with Docker only by creating a network and then running containers on it, e.g:

```sh
docker network create ${NETWORK}
docker container run ... --net=${NETWORK} --name=proxy ...
...
```